# Ubuntu and logitech mouse

Tags: logitech-unifying

Hi I have a Logitech mk320 mouse and keyboard combo and I lost the receiver! Can i buy a new mouse with a new receiver and pair it with the keyboard with solaar?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Logitech's technical specs for MK320](http://logitech-en-amr.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/14080/~/mk320-technical-specifications), the receiver has product ID C52B which is a Unifying receiver supported by Solaar. A user has confirmed this in the Solaar issue tracker: https://github.com/pwr/Solaar/issues/130

If you plan to buy a new Logitech mouse, be sure that it supports "Unifying" or it may not be compatible. A list of devices supported by Solaar can be found in the [Solaar repo](https://github.com/pwr/Solaar/blob/master/docs/devices.md).